# JQuery: Binding a click event to a non-clickable HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple div elements with the same class. I'm trying to bind an individual click event to each.

```
<div class="tile">Tile1</div>
<div class="tile">Tile2</div>
<div class="tile">Tile3</div>
...

$(".tile").click(this.handleClick);

var handleClick = function () {
  console.log("inside handle click");
};
```

Currently, the click event doesn't fire and nothing happens. If I bind the click event to the window instead of ".tile" like below, the click event fires perfectly well.

```
$(window).click(this.handleClick);
```

Any idea why what my issue is?

Answer (score 0):

`this` doesn't work as you  expect in this context. Try

```
function handleClick() {
  console.log("inside handle click");
};

$(".tile").click(handleClick);
```

You don't need `this` keyword to use variables and functions just assigned in the same scope.

This has a quite specific meanings in JavaScript. There're a lot articles about this in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably has something to do with your usage of `this`.

In your particular example, you bind `this.handleClick` as handler and only afterwards define the variable `handleClick` as a function - two ways in which it fails.

First of all, you need to forget about using `this` because it's not needed and probably doesn't refer to what you think it does. Second of all, either use a function definition or move the function declaration before it's used:

```
$(".tile").click(handleClick);

function handleClick() { // handleClick is defined in the whole scope
  console.log("inside handle click");
};
```

or

```
var handleClick = function () { // handleClick is defined from this line forward (in this scope)
  console.log("inside handle click");
};

$(".tile").click(handleClick);
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved by binding the click event to the element within the document, instead of the element itself.

```
$(document).on("click", ".tile", this.handleClick);
```